# Keras Flatten not creating 1D output

Tags: python-3.x, keras

I am trying to build a 1D CNN but I can't get the right dimensions passed to my last dense layer

The architecture of my model is

```
model_CNN=Sequential()
model_CNN.add(Conv1D(14, 29, activation='relu', input_shape=(X_train.shape[1], 1)))    
model_CNN.add(Conv1D(30, 22, activation='relu'))

model_CNN.add(Flatten())

model_CNN.add(Dense(176,activation='relu'))    
model_CNN.add(Dense(Y_train.shape[1],activation='linear'))
```

With a summary that looks like

```
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv1d_71 (Conv1D)           (None, 3304, 14)          420       
_________________________________________________________________
conv1d_72 (Conv1D)           (None, 3283, 30)          9270      
_________________________________________________________________
flatten_18 (Flatten)         (None, 98490)             0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_102 (Dense)            (None, 176)               17334416  
_________________________________________________________________
dense_103 (Dense)            (None, 5)                 885       
=================================================================
Total params: 17,344,991
Trainable params: 17,344,991
Non-trainable params: 0
```

When I try to fit my model, I confirm that my input shape is correct (240, 3332, 1), but then I get the following error

```
ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_103 
to have 2 dimensions, but got array with shape (240, 5, 1)
```

So my flatten function is not creating a 1D array, but also somehow the input only fails on the second dense layer, not the first. What's going on?

Comment: Is your `Y_train.shape[1]` correct?

Comment: Can you please check your output dimension(`Y_train`)? I think `Y_train` has shape of `(240,5,1)` And it should be `(240,5)`.

Comment: That fixed it! Thank you so much! I mindlessly added a dimension to all of my data without thinking